# Jumping between sub SMs in boost::msm

Tags: c++, boost-msm

I have two sub SMs inside my main SM. I want to be able to jump into either one from the main SM, but also jump from one sub SM to the other SM. But I can't. I'm able to jump from the main SM into the sub SMs and from *one* of the sub SM into the other, but when I add "mutual" transitions between the sub SM the compilation fails with ~10 errors complaining about different things. I suppose that is because the compiler goes into a recursive spin.

I suppose I can add a dummy state in the main SM with an anonymous transition into the target sub SM. But then I would loose the real event that trigged the transition and I don't want that (it contains data).

Here is some test code with the offending line commented out

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

namespace {

    using namespace boost::msm;
    using namespace boost::msm::front;
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    struct EvGotoSub1 {};
    struct EvGotoSub2 {};

    struct MainSM_;
    using Main = back::state_machine<MainSM_>;    
    struct Sub1SM_;
    using Sub1 = back::state_machine<Sub1SM_>;
    struct Sub2SM_;
    using Sub2 = back::state_machine<Sub2SM_>;

    struct Sub1SM_ : state_machine_def<Sub1SM_> {
        struct Started : state<> { };
        using initial_state = mpl::vector<Started>;
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        Row<Started, EvGotoSub2, Sub2, none, none>
        > {};
    };

    struct Sub2SM_ : state_machine_def<Sub2SM_> {
        struct Started : state<> { };
        using initial_state = mpl::vector<Started>;
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        // Uncomment line below to break things
        //Row<Started, EvGotoSub1, Sub1, none, none>
        > {};
    };

    struct MainSM_ : state_machine_def<MainSM_> {
        struct Started : state<> { };
        using initial_state = mpl::vector<Started>;
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        Row<Started, EvGotoSub1, Sub1, none, none>,
        Row<Started, EvGotoSub2, Sub2, none, none>
        > {};
    };
}

int main() {

    Main main;
    main.start();
    main.process_event(EvGotoSub1());
    main.process_event(EvGotoSub2());
    main.process_event(EvGotoSub1());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to nest `Sub2` inside `Sub1` and vice-versa, but that both are submachines to `Main` without any nesting.
You can exit from one submachine and go to the other by using [pseudo exit states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html#d0e875).

These exit states just forward the incoming event which you can then pass on to the other submachine by defining additional transitions in the transition table of `Main`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/state_machine_def.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/functor_row.hpp>

namespace {

    using namespace boost::msm;
    using namespace boost::msm::front;
    namespace mpl = boost::mpl;

    struct EvGotoSub1 { EvGotoSub1(int d1):d1(d1){} int d1;};
    struct EvGotoSub2 { EvGotoSub2(int d2):d2(d2){} int d2;};

    struct MainSM_;
    using Main = back::state_machine<MainSM_>;    
    struct Sub1SM_;
    using Sub1 = back::state_machine<Sub1SM_>;
    struct Sub2SM_;
    using Sub2 = back::state_machine<Sub2SM_>;

    struct Sub1SM_ : state_machine_def<Sub1SM_> {
        struct Started : state<> {  template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_entry(const Event& e, Fsm&) const { std::cout << "SUB2SM_ Started::on_entry(): d1="<<e.d1 << std::endl; } };
        struct Exit : exit_pseudo_state<EvGotoSub2> {};
        using initial_state = mpl::vector<Started>;
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
         Row<Started, EvGotoSub2, Exit, none, none>
        > {};
    };

    struct Sub2SM_ : state_machine_def<Sub2SM_> {
        struct Started : state<> {  template <class Event,class Fsm> void on_entry(const Event& e, Fsm&) const { std::cout << "SUB2SM_ Started::on_entry(): d2="<<e.d2 << std::endl; } };
        struct Exit : exit_pseudo_state<EvGotoSub1> {};
        using initial_state = mpl::vector<Started>;
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        Row<Started, EvGotoSub1, Exit, none, none>
        > {};
    };

    struct MainSM_ : state_machine_def<MainSM_> {
        struct Started : state<> { };
        using initial_state = mpl::vector<Started>;
        struct transition_table:mpl::vector<
        Row<Started, EvGotoSub1, Sub1, none, none>,
        Row<Started, EvGotoSub2, Sub2, none, none>,
        Row<Sub2::exit_pt<Sub2SM_::Exit>, EvGotoSub1, Sub1, none, none>,
        Row<Sub1::exit_pt<Sub1SM_::Exit>, EvGotoSub2, Sub2, none, none>
        > {};
    };
}


int main() {

    Main main;
    main.start();
    main.process_event(EvGotoSub1(0));
    main.process_event(EvGotoSub2(1));
    main.process_event(EvGotoSub1(2));
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d491442b38a24e82

As you can see, the event is not lost but forwarded.

A good ressource about the pseudo exit states can be found at http://redboltz.wikidot.com/exit-point-pseudo-state.

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct. This is exactly was I was looking for!